# Chrome Developer Tools Disabled by website

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I have recently visited a website and wanted to inspect its code. I am using Google Chrome, the latest open version.

When I tried to open the Developer Tools by clicking on the drop down menu on top right the setting was grayed out and I was unable to select it. Trying to use the shortcuts didnt work out as well.

The Developer tools works with other websites. I also tried to have it open on other website, then change to the one I wanted to inspect the code and the dev tools were turned off.

My question is, is there a way to enable the developer tools while accessing this website that prohibits me from inspecting its code? Or if that's not possible is there another way to inspect the code of that website?

Comment: Can you name the website? To answer your question, there is always a way to inspect the code of any website you visit -- worst case, you could always use a proxy like Fiddler that logs HTTP requests and responses.

Comment: @zinfandel its https://www.mutantbox.com/ but atm its down. but with a proxy it wouldnt be the same as with dev tools :/

Comment: I've just visited the page and my dev tools appear to work just fine.

Comment: @zinfandel well yeah, on the main menu its working, but if you select a server and enter the game it doesnt let you there. thats where i need it to work

Comment: Google does this as well: several sites located at sites.google.com/<<yoursite>> has inspection disabled (in chrome). I cannot tell how; I see no information in the source code telling me how this is done .. 

If I open the exact same page in other Chromium-based browsers (like Vivalid) I have no problem inspecting the source. So this is a Chrome feature only.

Comment: Just noticed this issue in gmail.com and drive.google.com. Pretty annoying and I see now answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or opening developer tools before visiting the website **instead** of the classic 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> shortcut works perfectly fine for me. I saw this problem on site christianityfaq.com